# Adding a MQTT Client to my angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, mqtt

I'm trying to make a MQTT client to my Ionic2/Angular 2 project using MQTT.js library but I just don't know how to implement it.
So fa I created a provider to my project called mqtt-client and then I've included the library typing

```
npm install mqtt --save
```

and then

```
npm install --save @types/mqtt
```

After that I've added the module to my provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Client, Packet, connect } from 'mqtt';

@Injectable()
export class MQTTClient {
  constructor(public http: Http,  public packet: Packet, public client:Client ) {
    console.log('Hello MqttClientProvider Provider');


  }

}
```

How do I continue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: Does this helps https://github.com/sjmf/ng2-mqtt-demo ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use ngx-mqtt which is a wrapper for MQTT.js for angular and it works with most versions of Angular which is why there is an x after ng

https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/

You should be able to get it up and running seamlessly following the instructions in the link above.